# jQuery animate image rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a nav bar with sub menus and an arrow to click on that will bring down the submenu (already using jQuery `slideToggle()`) and I am trying to use `jQueryRotate.js` to rotate the arrow, slowly, with the menu.

So... the arrow pointing up with the menu retracted and  arrow pointing down with the menu showing. I have tried to use jQuery `animate()` with no success.

**Here is my fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mYQNL/2/

The first and most evident problem is the arrow doesn't rotate back to pointing up when the menu is retracted.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer with the corrected fiddle.

Comment: @Sebsemillia Thanks for that! I mean, I'm not bad with CSS and HTML, there is just a few things that always throw me for a loop. So how does `#posiNav a {display: block; position: relative;}` achieve the desired effect? Also, from a user standpoint, right now I have the `li` set with `padding: 5px 0px;` therefore the anchor doesn't stretch from top to bottom. Now if I add it to `#posiNav a` it does, but do you think there should be some space in between `li`s that isn't part of the anchor?

Comment: @Sebsemillia finished product: https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/microsite/posiflex/home.aspx?

let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('rot')) {
    $(this).removeClass('rot').rotate({
        duration: 200,
        angle: 180,
        animateTo:0
  });
} else {
    $(this).addClass('rot').rotate({
        duration: 200,
        angle: 0,
        animateTo:180});
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYQNL/4/)

BTW: I would recommend using [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) instead of a jQuery library for rotating the image.

[jsFiddle with corrected HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/mYQNL/6/)

I would recommend you learning the basics of HTML and CSS, because without this you will never be able to create a website which will work perfectly and with good performance in all browsers and devices.

Take maybe a look at [Codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/html-css), they have some free courses there which cover the fundamentals.

Comment: That works great! Anyway to animate it so that it rotates at the speed the menu drops?

Comment: @metsales: I updated my answer, just play around with the duration until you have the desired time effect

Comment: @Tip_Top thanks for the feedback! The reason I had the button separate is because I will have a 'home page' for each of those buttons where if they click on the `li` it will go to the home page, whereas if they click on the arrow they can then select from a drop down menu.

It works a little better outside of JSFiddle because of the mouseover pointer, but other than making the whole `li` bring the drop down menu down would you think adding some padding to the arrow would help?

Comment: @tip_top I totally agree with you. I just wanted to answer the OP's question as he wanted it to and not confuse him with useability..

Comment: @metsales: btw, I just see that your list markdown is invalid.. you can't put the a outside the li, it has to be inside.

Comment: @Sebsemillia ...about that... I guess I was kind of taking the lazy way out because I wanted the hover to work when the cursor was over any part of the `li` not just the words, and didn't want to set padding and stuff like that. You think you could maybe help me with that? because a common issue I have been having lately is that I would like the whole `li` to be 'clickable' and with the word length of each `li` being different the 'clickable' area varies between each `li`

Comment: @Tip_Top I am inclined to say yes to that, and it could just be me, but I always feel like the page isn't as clean with hovering elements. Which is the reason I was shying towards the clickable arrow. btw, I really appreciate the feedback because I want to try and make this menu as intuitive as possible.

Comment: @Tip_Top That actually doesn't sound like a bad idea. So of the different options what is your top pick?

Comment: @metsales Sorry, I'm busy and out of office right now.. I'll try to look into it tomorrow, ok?

Comment: @Sebsemillia not a problem at all! I've been trying to play around with it, but no dice. Thanks for all the help! It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  When I go to that JSFiddle (in Chromium or Firefox), and click the arrow, I get `TypeError: $(...).removeClass(...).rotate is not a function`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it this way:

```
var currAngle = $(this).getRotateAngle();
if(currAngle == 180){
        $(this).rotate(0);
    }
    else{
        $(this).rotate(180);
    }
```

And to have more control over the rotation, use:

```
var currAngle = $(this).getRotateAngle();
if(currAngle == 180){
    $(this).rotate({
        duration:1300,
        angle:180,
        animateTo:0
    });
}
else{
    $(this).rotate({
        duration: 1300,
        angle:0,
        animateTo: 180
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#row-1").click(function(){
    value1 += delta1;
    delta1 = -delta1;
    $("#image1").rotate({ animateTo:value1});
});
```

add row-1 as an id to the column that the image is in, and then add image as an id to your image.